# Strange Network hotspot popup ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I have just experienced something weird due to a power outage my router was offline for about 1 hour when power was back on and i started up my computer something strange happened i got a popup message from an ubuntu application saying something about a network hotspot i have never made a connection to any sort of hotspot however a hotspot is close to where i live and is reachable but the strange thing is i didnt connect to my homenetwork manually so i couldnt missclick and when i restarted my device and it automatically connected to the same homenetwort it happened again i checked multiple times and i was still connected to my homenetwort when i restarted my computer for the third time i suddenly stopped
What could have happened here schould i be worried or do something please help [I have an image of the message in question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtEoi.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the network connection is activated, the NetworkManager service in Ubuntu tries to fetch a text file over HTTP to check whether it has Internet access over that connection. Other operating systems (Windows, Android) also do the same, only the URL differs.

If the HTTP query results in a redirect, or generally any response other than the expected one, the system assumes that it needs to go through a website-based login page first (called a "captive portal" login), because that's how such login pages typically work – they intercept all web requests and redirect them to the login page. For example, public Wi-Fi hotspots often ask for something like an email address, which is why this feature is called "hotspot check".

So whenever NetworkManager sees a redirect instead of the expected text, it opens a web browser window so that you could interact with the login page and do whatever it wants before you can get internet access.

In some cases, however, home routers/modems *also* perform the same kind of redirection when they don't have a working WAN connection yet (presumably so that they could inform the user that something is wrong). But as soon as the modem establishes its Internet connection it stops doing so.

So what sometimes happens is that the modem's Wi-Fi goes up first, your computer connects and does its Internet access check – it gets redirected by the modem to its error page and launches a web browser – but by the time the browser opens, the modem finally has established the ISP connection and no longer performs the annoying redirections, so the browser ends up hitting the *actual* web server instead.

(Which, in the case of NetworkManager's default configuration, doesn't really expect visitors and only has that one text file which says "NetworkManager is online" or something like that.)

Comment: Thanks for your help